# Access label in grid from a string name

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a loop which adds labels to certain grid columns and rows. I set the name of each label to "label_x_y", with x and y being its respective X and Y coordinates. I then need to access each label by their name "label_x_y" to set some of their background colours - how do I do this?

For example:

```
Label playSquare = new Label();
playSquare.Name = String.Format("playSquare_{0}_{1}", 25, 25);
playArea.Children.Add(playSquare);

playSquare_25_25.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

Comment: Would it be suitable for your use case to set the the label background colour before adding it to the playArea?

Comment: @ChristianH. unfortunately not, as they need to be dynamically changed according to their position in the grid.

Comment: This feels a bit hackish, and not very MVVM style, but one way to do it would be:

Label myLabel = playArea.Children.OfType<Label>().Where(l => l.Name == "labelName").FirstOrDefault();
            if (myLabel != null)
            {
                myLabel.Background = Brushes.Red; 
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Children` property to find the controls starting with name as 'playSquare'. This is the same property which you are using to add controls to layout control.

```
var labelControl = testStackPanel.Children
                                 .OfType<ContentControl>()
                                 .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("Label"));

foreach (var item in labelControl)
{
    item.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to do:

```
Label label = playArea.FindName($"playSquare_{x}_{y}") as Label
```

if playArea is the Grid

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set the `Grid.Column` and `Grid.Row` attached properties of the `Label` before you add it to the `Grid`?

```
Grid.SetColumn(playSquare, 25);
Grid.SetRow(playSquare, 25);
```

You could then simply use these properties to retrieve the `Label` by its position in the `Grid`:

```
int x = 25;
int y = 25;
Label label = playArea.Children.OfType<Label>()
    .FirstOrDefault(l => Grid.GetColumn(l) == x && Grid.GetRow(l) == y);
```

This is a better solution that trying to identify the `Label`'s position in the `Grid` using its name.